# C# - Help: Listview SelectedItems Invalid Index Value

Tags: winforms, listviewitem, invalidargumentexception

Im programming in WindowsForms, trying to Remove items from a listview using a button.
I tried with the following code:

```
private void btnQuitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listvPrincipal.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            while (listvPrincipal.Items.Count > 0)
                listvPrincipal.Items.Remove(listvPrincipal.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
```

But every time i select an item and click the "Remove" button, the following error occurs:

```
InvalidArgument = Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
```

I searched for this problem but every answer said the problem was that no item was selected and to solve it you should make sure " Items.Count > 0 ".

Before i press the button i make sure i have an item selected.

I have used the same code in another project and it works just fine. Im not sure why it doesn't work here. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking the `SelectedItems` property not the `Items` property:

```
private void btnQuitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (listvPrincipal.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        listvPrincipal.Items.Remove(listvPrincipal.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah my bad. Thanks a lot !